# Custom handshake data with Flask-SocketIO

Tags: python, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I have a Python server using Flask, that has a websocket connection using [Flask-SocketIO](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) . There is a similar question : 
[Send custom data along with handshakeData in socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745519/send-custom-data-along-with-handshakedata-in-socket-io) The idea is to do the same thing but instead of using Node, using Flask. I want the client to send some data in the connect event, for example:

```
var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", { query: "foo=bar" });
```

I haven't been able to get that custom data, and I can't rely on cookies due to the client's framework. A working solution is to have the connect event as usual, and then, in a custom event, get that information as a payload. But what we would want is to only have to do a connect event. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to access `request.args` in your connect handler? I think that should give you your query string arguments.

Answer (score 5):

As Miguel suggested in his comment you can simply do

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    foo = request.args.get('foo')
    # foo will be 'bar' when a client connects

socketio.run(app)
```

on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The global connect method gets called on server side. But not my connect method for a specific namespace. Are namespaces supporting query parameter?

Client Code

```
const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ds', { query: {name: "Test"} });
```

Server Code

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/ds')
def test_connect():
    foo = request.args.get('foo')
    print("CONNECT DS")
```

Comment: The danger with  this is that the query variables can be cached by servers so you do not want to send your sensitive data in the URL

Answer (score 0):

as of this time in 2021 you can send Auth data from [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/) client with

`sio.connect('http://localhost:6000/',auth={"authToken":"some auth token"})`